# Posting a file to a url with node

Tags: javascript, node.js, http-post, wget

I would like to do what `wget --post-file=foo.xpi http://localhost:8888/` does with nodejs so that it is cross platform.

I would like some help figuring out an easy to post a zip file to a given url.

I tried the `wget` npm package and that didn't seem to work, and I tried the `file-post` npm package which also did not work..

Any suggestions?

For what it's worth I'm trying to post a file to [Extension Auto-Installer](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/autoinstaller/)

Answer (score 2):

If it were me, I'd probably use the `request` [module](https://github.com/request/request#streaming) and just stream a file up.

```
fs.createReadStream('foo.xpi').pipe(request.put('http://localhost:8888/foo.xpi'));
```

Of course, you could also use POST if that makes more sense, and take in the file path as a parameter to a CLI tool etc.

*EDIT From Comments*

So, the requestjs code I showed is pretty straight forward, and does work. My thinking is that perhaps the corruption of your file comes b/c the file server can't handle the streamed upload (perhaps).  That said, you should also be able to post it w/o using the pipe syntax like so:

```
var req = request.post(url, function (err, resp, body) {
  if (err) {
    console.log('Error!');
  } else {
    console.log('URL: ' + body);
  }
});
var form = req.form();
form.append('file', fs.createReadStream(filepath));
```

Comment: It needs to be a post request because of the server that I am dealing with, also I want the tool to work on windows and osx without requiring any setup, so using wget is not an option.

Comment: ? I wasn't suggesting wget. The code I showed is in Node.  Instead of `request.put` you can do `request.post` and it works the same so long as the URL you're posting to will accept the file.

Comment: so I tried with `post` instead of `put` and that did not work, I'm not sure why I didn't get any error and I'm not sure how to debug this piping.

Comment: by "Of course, you could also use POST if that makes more sense, and take in the file path as a parameter to a CLI tool etc" I thought you meant using wget..

Comment: update your code with what you're trying now.  Make sure the URL you're posting to is correct.

Comment: I tried `fs.createReadStream(xpiPath).pipe(request.post('http://localhost:8888/'));`

Comment: ok I see an error on the server side: 1421989151524 addons.xpi WARN Download of install-shortener:27 failed: [Exception... "Component returned failure code: 0x8052000b (NS_ERROR_FILE_CORRUPTED) [nsIZipReader.open]"  nsresult: "0x8052000b (NS_ERROR_FILE_CORRUPTED)"  location: "JS frame :: resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm :: AI_loadManifest :: line 5267"  data: no] Stack trace: AI_loadManifest()@resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm:5267 < AI_onStopRequest()@resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm:5540 < <file:unknown>

Comment: So, this question is answered (in that you successfully posted the file using Node). The server-side error should probably be another question, because you'll want to show the code involved.

Comment: I'm not sure that is true, the error says the file is corrupted, and I know the server works with wget, so I wouldn't say this code works in the context of my question.

Comment: damn I tried your second approach and I get the same corrupted file error, so weird..

Comment: I do see `URL: ` logged too. the statusCode is 500 as expected (what I get with wget)